# Programmatically calc sum of rows in Excel

Tags: excel, sum, rows

[image: Excel Doc]

From the above screenshot, I'm trying to add multiple rows into the `F` column from cells `C` and `D`.

I have manually done some of them myself, ex:

Cell `F2` is `=SUM(C2+D2)`,
Cell `F3` is `=SUM(C3+D3)`

Is there a way to copy this sum forumla and increment it for the cell row number that it is in, or must I do every formula in column `F` manually?

Thanks!

Comment: I am guessing you don't know how to autofill. There is a box on the bottom right corner of any cell you select.  If you select cell `F2` and then click and drag that box down to the bottom of your data Excel fills all the formulas in for you.

Comment: Also I think this would be better fitted for [Superuser.com](http://superuser.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select cell with formula in column F. Grab the black square in the bottom right corner of the selected cell (pressing left mouse button). Move mouse 
to the last cell in column F. Release left mouse button. It's done.

Answer (score 1):

Say we want to setup cells **F2** thru **F100**

1. In cell **F2**, enter your formula.
2. Hi-light cells **F2** thru **F100**
3. Touch <kbd>CNTRL</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd>